# Display variable data from SQLite using base adapter and listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter

### Hi I am working on application consists of json notification that comes from parse and the application store it in SQLite i did that task but there is a big Problem to me and it is that i want to show stored notifications in a listview to display it in main activity that is my code

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {


 @Override
    public void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
        Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, splashscreen.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i); 
        
        
        Log.d("Alert: ", "Inserting from onReceive"); 
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            String alert = jsonObject.getString("alert");
            Log.d("Insert: ",alert); 
            String Message = jsonObject.getString("Message");
            Log.d("Title: ",Message); 
            String Date = jsonObject.getString("Date");
            Log.d("Date: ",Date); 
             
        
            DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(context);
          
            db.addnotification(new notification(alert,Message,Date));
            
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all notifications.."); 
            List<notification> notifications = db.getAllnotifications();       
             
            for (notification cn : notifications) {
                String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Title: " + cn.gettitle() + " ,Message: " + cn.getmessage()+ " ,Date: " + cn.gettimedate();
                // Writing notifications to log
                Log.d("Name: ", log);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you properly provide some insights on what exactly you want to achieve? Any error, problem that you are facing could help the community understanding what you actually got stucked

Comment: i want to display the json data which comes and store in sqlite in listview        (which "alert" "message" "date")

Comment: @Fabiano Francesconi

Comment: You can get it back from the database and then show it. What are you looking for in the question?

Comment: how to get it back ... @Diyoda

Comment: can you write the code for me according to my variables please ?

Comment: @Ahmed Can you add your DatabaseHandler  to your question, I think it is not a good idea to write your code. but I can help you.

Comment: @Diyoda give me your mail and i will send you the zip of my project

Comment: @Diyoda i added it please write my the code requried

Comment: @AhmedEssamMandour I an sorry, You should figure things out yourself and then cone to SO and ask relevant questions and move forward. You should not ask for code on SO.

Answer (score 0):

In progress,,,

1. Write your Dao class (in your case, DatabaseHandler class) to get the data from the database (Or you can write a content provider- the cool way of achieving this.)

An example dao class is as follows,

```
public class DocumentRepository {

            public static final String TABLE_DOCUMENT = "document";
            public static final String COLUMN_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
            public static final String RECORD_ID = "record_id";
            public static final String UUID_DOCUMENT_NAME = "unique_file_name";

            public static final String DOCUMENT_TABLE_CREATE = "create table if not exists "
                    + TABLE_DOCUMENT + "(" + COLUMN_ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + RECORD_ID
                    + " integer , " + UUID_DOCUMENT_NAME
                    + " text );";
            private Context context;

            public DocumentRepository(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }


            public ArrayList<Document> geDocuments(Integer customerId) {
                ArrayList<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
                String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DOCUMENT + " WHERE " + RECORD_ID + " = '" + customerId + "'";
                SQLiteDatabase database = ......// create a instance of your SqliteDatabase implementation 
                Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Document document = new Document();
                        document.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                        document.setUniqueIdentifier(cursor.getString(3));
                        documents.add(document);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                return documents;
            }
        }
```

2. Get the list of objects that you want to display in the ListView.

in this example `geDocuments()` will give you the list of objects.

3. Inject it into your Adapter and set the Adapter for the listView reference.

Answer (score 0):

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notificationsbase";

// notifications table name
private static final String TABLE_notifications = "notifications";

// notifications Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_title = "title";
private static final String KEY_message = "message";
private static final String KEY_timedate = "timedate";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_notificationS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_notifications + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_title + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_message + " TEXT ,"  + KEY_timedate + " NUMERIC " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_notificationS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_notifications);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new notification
void addnotification(notification notification) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_title, notification.gettitle());            // title
    values.put(KEY_message, notification.getmessage());       // message
    values.put(KEY_timedate, notification.gettimedate());    // timedate

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_notifications, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single notification
notification getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_notifications, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_title, KEY_message, KEY_timedate }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    notification notifications = new notification(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
    // return contact
    return notifications;
}

// Getting All notifications
public List<notification> getAllnotifications() {
    List<notification> notificationList = new ArrayList<notification>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_notifications;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            notification notification = new notification();
            notification.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            notification.settitle(cursor.getString(1));
            notification.setmessage(cursor.getString(2));
            notification.settimedate(cursor.getString(3));
            // Adding notification to list
            notificationList.add(notification);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return notification list
    return notificationList;
}

// Updating single notification
public int updatenotification(notification notification) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_title, notification.gettitle());
    values.put(KEY_message, notification.getmessage());
    values.put(KEY_timedate, notification.gettimedate());


    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_notifications, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(notification.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single notification
public void deletenotification(notification notification) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_notifications, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(notification.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting notifications Count
public int getnotificationsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_notifications;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

public void open() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class notification
```

{

```
//private variables
int id;
String title;
String message;
String timedate;


// Empty constructor
public notification(){

}
// constructor
public notification(int id, String title, String message, String timedate){
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.message = message;
    this.timedate = timedate;


}

// constructor
public notification(String title, String message, String timedate){
    this.title = title;
    this.message = message;
    this.timedate = timedate;

}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this.id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

// getting title
public String gettitle(){
    return this.title;
}

// setting title
public void settitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

// getting message
public String getmessage(){
    return this.message;
}

// setting message
public void setmessage(String message){
    this.message = message;
}

// getting timedate
public String gettimedate(){
    return this.timedate;
}

// setting message
public void settimedate(String timedate){
    this.timedate = timedate;
}
```

}